# Copy all folders that contain file(s) with the given extension

Tags: find, osx, file-copy

In a Mac Terminal, I want to find all directories that contain at least one file with the specified extension and copy them somewhere else. I found `find . -iname '*.jpg' -exec dirname {} \;` which seems to find all directories containing a `*.jpg` file, but I'm not sure how to copy them. I tried combining it with `rsync` but couldn't get it to work. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `bash` friendly one liner that copies any folders that have a jpg in them into a folder called backup while maintaining directory structure

```
mkdir backup; for folder in $(find . -type f -name '*.jpg' | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' |sort |uniq); do cp -r --parents $folder backup; done
```

First it creates an empty `backup` folder then the `find` command looks for all the files in the current directory that end with `.jpg`. The `sed`, `sort`, and `uniq` commands trim the find output to just the directory names and remove repeats. Finally the `cp -r --parents` in a loop copies the folders over recursively while creating any files that are missing.

you can get around using `sed -r` by using the `-printf` flag with `find` like so

```
mkdir backup; for folder in $(find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -printf "%h\n" |sort |uniq); do cp -r --parents $folder backup; done
```

if your `find` doesn't support `-printf` you can try using `grep`

```
mkdir backup; for folder in $(find . -type f -name '*.jpg' | grep -o "\(.*\)/" |sort |uniq); do cp -r --parents $folder backup; done
```

Comment: This looks prefect but doesn’t work in Mac Terminal. Can you please edit it to work in Terminal? Thanks

Comment: Can you describe the error you're getting? I don't have a mac to test on. Those commands should be cross platform between unix based systems.

Comment: This is what i get:
`sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]`

Comment: added a solution that doesn't depend on `sed -r` see if that works

Comment: This is what I get now: `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`

Comment: try the solution with `grep`?

Comment: Perfect, now it works finally. Only thing I changed was `cp -r --parents` to `rsync -r`.
Only spaces makes problem in folder names. Is there any way how to solve it?

Comment: Try using `sed` to escape all the spaces with a \ ?

Comment: Using sed `sed '/ /\\ /g'`? And the position is after `grep`?

Comment: maybe try ` sed 's/ /\\ /' `? and yes that's where it would go.

Comment: Still the same..

Comment: Solved. Problem was with hidden files. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

To find all files with the extension `.py`, this should work on OS X shells:

`find . *.py -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} cp -r {} /some/dir/name/`

Note:

- `find -print0` prints files terminated with a null char instead of a newline, and `xargs -0` is used for input in that format. This is to better handle filenames and paths that have spaces or other whitespace, which is otherwise often a headache.
- OS X uses different versions of `find` and `cp` than Linux/GNU does, so while *this* example would work with GNU utilities, many examples or answers for similar questions that use GNU utilities *do not* work on OS X.

Comment: Works only for files, not for the directories and all content.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. You want to find files by extension, and then copy those *and* everything else in their folders they are in?

Comment: Yes, that was my question